# How to update "Administrator" user password of a Windows Virtual Machine in Softlayer using slcli or sl api?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I created a windows virtual machine and later on changed the Administrator password. Is there a way to update the password which shows in UI using Softlayer command line or Softlayer API's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep it is possible see this code using the Softlayer's Python client:

```
"""
Edit a password for a device.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/editObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password/

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The software component password id which contains the password.
passwordId = 8409127

username = "newUserEdit"
password = "newPassEdit"

# optional field
notes = "my optional note"

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
passwordService = client['SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password']

# Build a SoftLayer_Software_Component_Password object
templatePass = {
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
    "notes": notes,
}

try:
    result = passwordService.editObject(templatePass, id=passwordId)
    print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to edit the password. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

you only need to know the software component id to edit, this code can help you to get the software components for a bare metal server for example:

```
"""
Get the passwords for a server.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getSoftwareComponents

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

serverId = 179996

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
serverService = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server']

objectMask = 'mask[passwords,softwareLicense]'

try:
    components = serverService.getSoftwareComponents(id=serverId, mask=objectMask)
    print(json.dumps(components, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the passwords faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

But keep in mid that using the API or the Softlayer's control portal when you change the password you only are changing the password value in the Softlayer's database and not the password for the machine, if you want change the passwrd on the machine you need to log on to the machine and change it manually.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for response. But this is not working for me. As, I am using virtual server I replace "SoftLayer_Hardware_Server" to "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest". When I use the softwareId for password, it's giving below error "Unable to find object with id of". Do, you this work for Virtual Servers too ?

Comment: yep it works as well for virtual servers, the issue is because the id does not exist in your account are you sure that you changed the ids in the script?